# Missing ALTER TABLE dependency using SMO DependencyWalker

Tags: sql, sql-server, smo

I am using powershell SMO `DependencyWalker` and `Scripter` to find the all dependencies of a table in a SQL Server database and then generating scripts to CREATE and DROP the table and those dependencies. `DependencyWalker` is successfully finding most of the dependencies, but does not find certain stored procedures that I believe it should.

For example, given these table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
   [UniqueID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MyOtherTable(
   [UniqueID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable] FOREIGN KEY([UniqueID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[MyOtherTable] ([UniqueID])
```

And the following stored procedures that reference the table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyTableResumeConstraintChecking]
AS
    ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable
    RETURN
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyTableSuspendConstraintChecking]
AS
    ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable_MyOtherTable
    RETURN
GO
```

I would expect that the following powershell script would find the stored procedures as dependencies:

```
$SmoServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Server') $server
$dbObject = $SmoServer.Databases["MyDatabase"]
$tables = $dbObject.Tables | where { !$_.IsSystemObject }
$urns = $tables | foreach { $_.Urn }

$walker = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.DependencyWalker' $SmoServer
$tree = $walker.DiscoverDependencies($urns, $false)
$depCollection = $walker.WalkDependencies($tree)

$dependencies = $depCollection | foreach { $_.Urn }
```

This will find all other stored procedures that use `MyTable` (ones with typical `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc. calls). However, it will NOT find these `*ConstraintChecking` procedures that reference the table only via `ALTER TABLE`.

It should be noted that SSMS does not recognize these procedures as a dependency of the table either (when using `View Dependencies`).

I have tried to use other mechanisms for finding dependencies such as `sp_depends` and `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`, but those behave the same as `DependencyWalker` in this situation.

Using SMO in powershell and given a table URN, how do I find the URN of dependencies such as this?

Comment: My testing shows that DDL statements don't show up in any of the DMVs used to track dependencies (sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities, sys.sql_expression_dependencies, etc) and since SMO is just sitting on top of those (I'd have to run a trace to determine which), you might be out of luck. If the number of such procs is small (and depending on your use case), you could treat them as a special case. That is always drop/create those ones and additionally those found by DependencyWalker.

Comment: @BenThul I was a bit afraid that this wouldn't be possible, so thanks for a bit of confirmation. Right now it is really just these two, but I am worried about somebody adding a new procedure that isn't picked up as a dependency in the future. Let's hope code review and unit tests catch it!

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, you'll catch it one way or another! :)